# how to send EmailId or Device token as parameter using AFNetworking with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I need to send an email ID to a server to reset this email address using AFNetworking.

```
SSAFRequest *afm= [[SSAFRequest alloc]init];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"email": @"a@b.com"};
[afm AfRequest_POST_Params:urlWithQuerystring urlWithQuerystring:urlWithQuerystring params:params :^(id JSON, NSError *error) {
    if(JSON!=Nil  && ![JSON isEqual:[[NSNull alloc]init]]) {


}];
```

This is my AFNetworking code:

```
-(void)AfRequest_POST_Params:(NSString *)baseUrl urlWithQuerystring:(NSString *)urlstring params:(NSDictionary *)parameters:(void (^)(id result, NSError *error))block {

NSLog(@"AfRequest_POST_Params ----%@ %@",baseUrl,urlstring);

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

[manager POST:baseUrl parameters:parameters
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
         NSLog(@"****Success****");
        block(responseObject,nil);

     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
         block(nil,error);

     }
 ];
```

}

But I don't know what I am missing in my code. This is the error I am getting:

```
<0x16d95210 SSLoginViewController.m:(821)> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x16ec5cd0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

please suggest me on this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got this error when the JSON parameters I was sending were incorrectly formatted. Where are you sending the parameters? I see you are passing `Nil` to the `POST:parameters:success:failure:` method.

Comment: i am sending correct parameters, may question is how to emailId, since emailid contains special characters

Comment: In your first section of code you are calling
    `[afm AfRequest_POST_Params:urlWithQuerystring urlWithQuerystring:urlWithQuerystring params:params :^(id JSON, NSError *error) {`

But you've posted the method code for
    `-(void)AfRequest_POST_text:(NSString *)baseUrl :`

What does `AfRequest_POST_Params` look like?

Comment: Hey Flex, I edited the code, please check once

Comment: I fixed this issue, Thanks everyone